# How to access the "real" object behind cells in DataRow

Tags: c#, datagridview, datarow

I wanna associate a custom object to each cell in a `DataTable`'s `DataRow` so that, on the events I get from the DataGridView, I can customize coloring and other behavior. So, when I add a new row, I do the following:

```
  DataRow oRow = dtItens.NewRow();
  oRow["CodFamilia"] = new ClsCelula(TipoCelula.tcMostrar, "", Color.White);
  oRow["Familia"] = new ClsCelula(TipoCelula.tcMostrar, "", Color.White);
  oRow["Item"] = new ClsCelula(TipoCelula.tcMostrar, "", Color.White);
  oRow["Descricao"] = new ClsCelula(TipoCelula.tcMostrar, "", Color.White);
  oRow["Referencia"] = new ClsCelula(TipoCelula.tcMostrar, "Saldo Inicial", Color.Aqua);
  dtItens.Rows.Add(oRow);
```

On the DataGridView's CellFormatting event, I want to get my ClsCelula object to read it's properties, like below:

```
Object oCelula = dtItens.Rows[e.RowIndex][e.ColumnIndex];
if (oCelula != null)
{
  if (oCelula is ClsCelula)
  {
    ClsCelula oValorCelula = (ClsCelula)oCelula;
    e.CellStyle.BackColor = oValorCelula.Cor;
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't work, since probably the code is calling `ToString()` when I read the Row/Column index, so oCelula is always a `System.String`. Is there any way around this? How can I access the "real" object?

Comment: If you have an object representation, why are you using DataTable? You can bind direct to the object-model...

Comment: Really? Didn't know I could do that with the DataGridView. How can I do that?

Comment: @Marc, got it here (http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-collection). Put it as an answer, since it's what I actually needed, so I can give you the credit! Tks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are working from an object model, there seems to be no need to use `DataTable` here **all** - just set the `DataSource` to a `List<T>` (or better: `BindingList<T>`) and away you go! `DataGridView` is perfectly happy binding to objects, and the underlying object is just [`.DataBoundItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem.aspx) on each row.

Note - for two-way data-binding (i.e. If you want the grid to update when you edit an object directly through code) you might want to use `BindingList<T>` **and** implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` - but this isn't necessary if you just want to display a list and edit items via the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Several options here:

- create `DataTable` from your own `DataColumn` objects, and specify the each column object type as `ClsCelula`.  You'll have problems formatting it for the grid, in this case.
- create second invisible i.e. shadow column for each object created, then in it put the index of the object in some `Dictionary<int, ClsCelula>` or such, where index would be some kind of autoincrement number you will have to create and maintain.
- do what Marc says in the comment.  That is the best thing you can do here.

Comment: I totally agree that Marc's option is the best one. I just didn't know that it was possible. I'm looking it up on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I found such thing in my code: `dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value`. You might have to cast that to a particular type.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but anyway:

```
DataGridRecord obj = (DataGridRecord)Rows[args.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
```